# HikaShop product menu scrolling issue

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a HikaShop site, using a Bootstrap template with the Product category module displayed on the right hand side:

[https://www.thhs.co.uk/][1]

I want to remove the functionality of the scrolling when a category option is clicked and the sub menu opened. How can I modify my code?

I believe this is the file that is controlling the sliders:

```
/**
 * @package HikaShop for Joomla!
 * @version 4.4.2
 * @author  hikashop.com
 * @copyright   (C) 2010-2021 HIKARI SOFTWARE. All rights reserved.
 * @license GNU/GPLv3 http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?><?php
class hikashopSlidersHelper {
    var $ctrl = 'sliders';
    var $tabs = null;
    var $openPanel = false;
    var $mode = null;
    var $count = 0;
    var $name = '';
    var $options = null;

    function __construct() {
        if(!HIKASHOP_J30) {
            $this->mode = 'sliders';
        } else {
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            if((hikashop_isClient('administrator') && HIKASHOP_BACK_RESPONSIVE) || (!hikashop_isClient('administrator') && HIKASHOP_RESPONSIVE)){
                $this->mode = 'bootstrap';
            }else{
                $this->mode = 'sliders';
            }
        }
    }

    function startPane($name) { return $this->start($name); }
    function startPanel($text, $id, $child = 0, $toOpen = 0) { return $this->panel($text, $id, $child, $toOpen); }
    function endPanel() { return ''; }
    function endPane() { return $this->end(); }

    function setOptions($options = array()) {
        if($this->options == null)
            $this->options = $options;
        else
            $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);
    }

    function start($name, $options = array()) {
        $ret = '';
        if($this->mode == 'pane') {
            jimport('joomla.html.pane');
            if(!empty($this->options))
                $options = array_merge($options, $this->options);
            $this->tabs = JPane::getInstance('sliders', $options);
            $ret .= $this->tabs->startPane($name);
        } elseif($this->mode == 'sliders') {
            if(!empty($this->options))
                $options = array_merge($options, $this->options);
            $ret .= JHtml::_('sliders.start', $name, $options);
        } else {
            if($this->options == null)
                $this->options = $options;
            else
                $this->options = array_merge($this->options, $options);
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->count = 0;
            $ret .= '<div class="accordion" id="'.$name.'">';
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function panel($text, $id, $child = 0, $toOpen = 0) {
        $ret = '';
        if($child) $child = 'has-child';
        else $child = '';

        if($this->mode == 'pane') {
            if($this->openPanel)
                $ret .= $this->tabs->endPanel();
            $ret .= $this->tabs->startPanel($text, $id);
            $this->openPanel = true;
        } elseif($this->mode == 'sliders') {
            $ret .= JHtml::_('sliders.panel', JText::_($text), $id);
        } else {
            if($this->openPanel)
                $ret .= $this->_closePanel();

            $open = '';
            $this->options['displayFirst'] = isset($this->options['displayFirst'])?$this->options['displayFirst']:1;
            if($toOpen || ($this->options['displayFirst'] && (isset($this->options['startOffset']) && $this->options['startOffset'] == $this->count || $this->count == 0)))
                $open = 'in';

            $this->count++;

            $text = trim($text);
            if(preg_match('#<a .*>.*</a>#i', $text))
                $text = '</a>' . str_replace('</a>', '', $text);

            $ret .= '
<div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading '.$child.'">
            <h4>
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#'.$this->name.'" href="#'.$id.'">
                    '.$text.'
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="'.$id.'" class="accordion-body collapse '.$open.'">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
';
            $this->openPanel = true;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function _closePanel() {
        if(!$this->openPanel)
            return '';
        $this->openPanel = false;
        return '</div></div></div>';
    }

    function end() {
        $ret = '';
        if($this->mode == 'pane') {
            if($this->openPanel)
                $ret .= $this->tabs->endPanel();
            $ret .= $this->tabs->endPane();
        } elseif($this->mode == 'sliders') {
            $ret .= JHtml::_('sliders.end');
        } else {
            if($this->openPanel)
                $ret .= $this->_closePanel();
            $ret .= '</div>';
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: For questions that relate to Joomla or its extensions, please ask on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This page appears to be abandoned.  Did you resolve your question yourself?